# How to run Multiple Methods one after another on new thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have built my first Windows Form with C# and I am starting to run into some not responding issues. This only happens when I start clicking somewhere else or start doing something else. I have researched some and learned that threading may help, but cannot figure out exactly how I should do this. Below is what I am trying right now.

```
 private void bPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
bPrint.Enabled = false;
            string cusNo = Strings.Left(cbCustomerList.SelectedItem.ToString(), 4);
            ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();


                        switch (cusNo)
            {

                case "4018":

                    try
                    {
                        Thread backgroundThread2 = new Thread(
                        new ThreadStart(() =>

                            FixPhoneNumbers(orderData, cusNo, dtpBeginDate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,
                            Settings.Default["Location"].ToString(), lProgress)));


                        backgroundThread2.Start();
                        Thread backgroundThread3 = new Thread(
                        new ThreadStart(() =>

                            CreateBol(orderData, cusNo, dtpBeginDate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,
                             Settings.Default["Location"].ToString(), lProgress)));

                        backgroundThread3.Start();
                        Thread backgroundThread4 = new Thread(
                        new ThreadStart(() =>

                            CreateUccPerLine(orderData, cusNo, dtpEndDate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,
                            Settings.Default["Location"].ToString(), lProgress)));


                        backgroundThread4.Start();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Loading " + ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                            MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);

                    }
                    finally
                    {

                        Thread backgroundThread1 = new Thread(
                        new ThreadStart(() =>

                            AssignProNumber(orderData, cusNo, dtpBeginDate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,
                               Settings.Default["Location"].ToString(), lProgress)));


                        backgroundThread1.Start();

                        LoadDS(orderData, cusNo, dtpBeginDate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,
                            Settings.Default["Location"].ToString(), lProgress);


                        PrintReport(orderData, reportDocument, "psWalmart.rpt",
                            Settings.Default["RegularPrinter"].ToString(), Settings.Default["LabelPrinter"].ToString());


                        PrintReport(orderData, reportDocument, "lbWalmart.rpt",
                            Settings.Default["RegularPrinter"].ToString(), Settings.Default["LabelPrinter"].ToString());

                        PrintReport(orderData, reportDocument, "boWalmart.rpt",
                            Settings.Default["RegularPrinter"].ToString(), Settings.Default["LabelPrinter"].ToString());

                        PrintReport(orderData, reportDocument, "qtyOrderedReport.rpt",
                            Settings.Default["RegularPrinter"].ToString(), Settings.Default["LabelPrinter"].ToString());

                        PrintReport(orderData, reportDocument, "qtyOrderedGreaterOne.rpt",
                            Settings.Default["RegularPrinter"].ToString(), Settings.Default["LabelPrinter"].ToString());
                    }



                    break;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `async/await` yet?

Comment: I would highly recommend not to start of you WinForms programming experience with threading. If you do so anyway, please read some tutorials about the topic. Threading is one of the most complex things you could do. Anyway, What exactly is your goal?

Comment: I have not looked at async/await yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new way of doing things like this is to use a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

**example**

```
private void bPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        FixPhoneNumbers(orderData, cusNo, dtpBeginDate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,
                        Settings.Default["Location"].ToString(), lProgress)))
    });
}
```

**You can also run multiple tasks**

```
private void bPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task1 = DoWorkAsync();
    var task2 = DoMoreWorkAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

[Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do I just do that for each method? does it wait for the first to complete before starting the next?

Comment: If he wants to understand threading he should learn about threads the "oldschool" way before moving on to tasks. If he just needs to get shit done, tasks are the thing to do!

Comment: @Ryan based on how your code is structured, it seems you want to it for each method. I would create multiple tasks then use WhenAll as I noted in the answer. WhenAll returns a task which represents the action of waiting until everything has completed and doesn't block.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé feel to add another comment with links to recommended threading sources.

Comment: What would my return type need to be on my methods? Right now they are all "public static void". await? async?

Comment: @Ryan async void on the button click event. Just be mindful of blocking on the UI. Hence the use of WhenAll. You may also want to consider if this impacts any UI elements like controls etc.

Comment: I assume there is a reference or assembly I need to add for tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Code executing inside a thread executes sequentially, so to run multiple methods one after the other, you just write them on separate lines inside your threaded code like you would any C# code.

I highly recommend checking out [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) in c# rather than threads, they are a little bit easier.

Also possibly Async/Await is worth checking out, but I'm not sure how well winforms will support that.

Answer (score -1):

Ryan,

I have used threading to basically handle Batch Processing in an ASP.NET site. This thread process will run the method ProcessMyData() in another thread.

```
//Create new object and start processing
MySite.Data.ProcessData Batch = new Data.ProcessData();
Batch.StartBatchProcessing();

//The StartBatchProcessing() Creates the new thread
public void StartBatchProcessing()
{    
    //ProcessMyData is the main method that will process the batch data
    Thread newThread = new Thread(this.ProcessMyData); //another thread
    newThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
    newThread.Start();
}
```

Reference the [blog post at this link](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2014/04/04/run-batch-jobs-in-asp-net-and-iis) for additional details